# Os Cantos Sertanejos by Villa-Lobos?

Tags: classical-music

I got a reference to a composition "Os Cantos Sertanejos" by Heitor Villa-Lobos in the sixth paragraph of the following article:

https://anovademocracia.com.br/no-198/7625-villa-lobos-musica-erudita-popular-brasileira?fbclid=IwAR01h2c2Bs8T7-OFirdD-AZszzl75LTDPD5AxX6hfmgBNSSD4a4GJ3fOecQ

Is the composition genuine, and if so may you kindly provide a link to a performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the article:

> In 1905, Villa-Lobos traveled to the Northeast having an intense contact with the folkloric richness of the region, which inspired him to write the piece for small orchestra Os sertanejos.

This piece is probably "Cânticos sertanejos", subtitled 'Fantasia característica' (W013) written in 1907 for 2 Violins, Viola, Cello, Contrabass, Piano. Villa-Lobos also arranged the piece for flute, clarinet and strings (W014). [source [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Heitor_Villa-Lobos)].

The score was long considered lost, but the piece was performed as part of the 48th Annual Festival Villa-Lobos, organized by the Museu Villa-Lobos in 2010 [source: [The Villa-Lobos Magazine](http://villa-lobos.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-villa-lobos-score.html)].

The piece is also listed in the [catalog](http://museuvillalobos.org.br/ingles/bancodad/VLSO_1.0.pdf) of the composer's works.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the music on Youtube or Spotify.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I can't find it either, it looks like no recording has been released.